# Single custom post type's menu ancestor/parent is Posts archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

1. I have created a theme by copying `twentyeleven` default theme.
2. I have also installed a module [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) and created a custom post type called "Book".
3. I have gone to `Settings -> Reading` and set `Front page displays` to `Static page` and set my Front Page to a page called `Home` and my Posts page to a page called `News & Press`.
4. I have gone to `Appearance -> Menus` and created a new custom menu. I put `Home`, `News & Press`, and `Books` (just a static page) pages to my menu item. Under `Books` menu item I've also added a few `Book` custom post type posts as children.

Now when I open a `Book` custom post type page, which is a child menu item of `Books` page, the menu highlights `News & Press` as the custom post type's parent, as well as the `Books` page.

I don't want this behavior, as highlighting the `News & Press` as the parent of a `Book` custom post type is completely wrong.

I have done a lot of searching around, and seen a lot of fixes that [suggest using jQuery](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-parent?replies=30#post-1917084), [and also some php fixes](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-parent?replies=30#post-1775314) which both use menu item id's which is just a bandaid fix, and not something that I would consider an actual fix to the problem because what about people who browse with javascript off, and if I used the PHP fix, then what if the menu item id's changed? I wanted to come here and see if anyone has actually managed to fix this broken behaviour with custom post types menu parent/ancestor highlighting.

Comment: It's about your nav menus. You should be sharing this code parts of your theme and improve the question.